# reading associative arrays from file

Tags: bash

I have a file with content:

```
( [datname]=template1 [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8 )
( [datname]=template0 [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8 )
( [datname]=postgres [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8 )
( [datname]=some\ stupid\ name [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8 )
( [datname]=jqerqwer,\ werwer [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8 )
```

I would to read every line and push context to associative array variable. I have no success with following code:

```
(cat <<EOF
( [datname]=template1 [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8)
( [datname]=template0 [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8 )
EOF                      
) |                      
while read r             
do                       
   declare -A row=("$r") 
   echo ${row[datname]}  
done;
```

I got a error:

```
test3.sh: line 8: row: ( [datname]=template1 [datctype]=cs_CZ.utf-8 ): must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

Is possible read array from file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the following two changes: Remove the parentheses in the declare statement, and use `read` with the option `-r` (disable escape chars):

```
while read -r line; do
   declare -A row="$line" 
    ...  
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses from your `declare` statement since they're already in your data.

```
declare -A row="$r"
```